# Coloring a specified char in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a minesweeper console game and I want to make it a bit more beautiful. I found some coloring libraries from the internet. and used them.
the library is:

```
// ConsoleColor.h

#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

inline std::ostream& blue(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, FOREGROUND_BLUE
              |FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    return s;
}

inline std::ostream& red(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 
                FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    return s;
}

inline std::ostream& green(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 
              FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    return s;
}

inline std::ostream& yellow(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 
         FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    return s;
}

inline std::ostream& white(std::ostream &s)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout, 
       FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    return s;
}

struct color {
    color(WORD attribute):m_color(attribute){};
    WORD m_color;
};

template <class _Elem, class _Traits>
std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>& 
      operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>& i, color& c)
{
    HANDLE hStdout=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hStdout,c.m_color);
    return i;
}
```

It works fine but I have a question. is there anyway to colorize a character in cpp? for example I want to print all 'X' of my program red. is is possible?
thanks for helping

Comment: You can always write a custom print function, say `fancy_print()`, that goes through every character of the string to be printed and adds color codes to certain characters as per your wish.

Comment: @domsson hello friend. you mean I write a function with a cout and write some conditions for it true?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be my approach. Although, to be fair, I haven't looked at how that color library works.

Comment: @domsson It seems good, but I get confused, what is the argument for this function?

Comment: The string you want to print, I would assume. Or the character. Depends on the design of the rest of your code: does it print one character at a time or one line at a time?

Comment: @domsson usually I print some arrays and their counters(example "i" & j etc)

Comment: Doing console tricks in Windows is futile... No one is going to bother. Please consider learning proper Windows GUI developing.

Comment: If I read the question correctly: No, you can't set that kind of conditional formatting to be done automatically. You have to do it yourself. For a game like this, with very limited set of possible characters, you might want to create function like `put_X(int column, int row, int color);` (replace color type with correct one, it's probably not `int`...).

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis If programming as a hobby, then writing text based programs is just fine. Especially when learning, it's much easier to concentrate on learning the language, when one does not have to learn the entire GUI framework to get anything to work or to understand all the code in their own program.

Comment: @Hyde but he is *not* learning the language. He tries to do something very Windows specific.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Actually I'm learning C++ in university (Computer Engineering) and my project is implementing a MineSweeper, I've done everything and it works ok. but the thing is I want to make it a bit more attractive to get more scores :D is GUI hard? can I learn it fast to make the job done sooner?

Comment: Going GUI inevitably introduces a road block for *everyone* new to programming: You're going to have to learn a whole new paradigm. Your program no longer is a sequence of statements that are executed in an obvious order. You have entered the realm of event-based programming. Code you author contributes only a tiny portion to a complex state machine, with state transitions largely invisible. It takes years of experience to understand, when you are about to leave the happy path, and how to respond when the Black Box strikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, what you're asking for is entirely possible, though it appears that only a few people know much about the applicable parts of the library. Setting the highlight color with a manipulator adds a little bit more work, but not a whole lot. Code could look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

class attribute { 
    DWORD attrib;
public:
    attribute(DWORD attrib) : attrib(attrib) {}
    DWORD operator()() const { return attrib; }
};

class outbuf : public std::streambuf {
    HANDLE h;
    DWORD default_color = FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_BLUE;
    DWORD highlight_color = FOREGROUND_GREEN;  
public:
    outbuf(HANDLE h) : h(h) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, default_color);
    }

    void set_highlight(DWORD color) { highlight_color = color; }

protected:
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override {
        if (c != EOF) {
            if (c == 'x') {
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, highlight_color);
                DWORD written;
                WriteConsole(h, &c, 1, &written, nullptr);
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, default_color);
            }
            else {
                DWORD written;
                WriteConsole(h, &c, 1, &written, nullptr);
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, attribute a) { 
    outbuf *out = dynamic_cast<outbuf *>(os.rdbuf());
    if (out) {
        out->set_highlight(a());
    }
    return os;
}

int main() { 
    outbuf buf(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));

    attribute red{FOREGROUND_RED};
    attribute blue{FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY};

    std::cout.rdbuf(&buf);
    std::cout << "oxen\n" << red << "axis\n" << blue << "waxy";
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for your good job, I appreciate it. and the second question is is there anyway to make this library works like this:
for example when we write `cout << red << "our text"`;` it looks through the sentence and make only x red? it will be amazing! thanks

Comment: The console supports [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), if [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) (Windows version requirements aren't spelled out, though). With that, you could simply declare a variable `auto const red{"\x1b[91m"};` and use that to switch to red text color: `cout << red << "red text";`.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question very well. look if you use that normal library, if you write something like this: `cout << red << "text"` it will make the whole text red. I am asking could you please change that library to a form that it only make the 'X' red? for example if we use the same mentioned code, it only make the X red. thanks.

Comment: @sem: That's *exactly*, what this answer does. Not that I think that this would be particularly useful in any given application. A library that allows a user to color arbitrary text output using arbitrary color values is far more versatile, than a library that allows you to apply color to a single, pre-defined character. Are you going to switch libraries if in the future you decide to no longer color the character `x`, but rather the capital letter `X`?

Comment: @iinspectable You know the thing is I have 2 options: first is I go and learn GUI which I know nothing about now, and second I make some visuals to the console based game. I colored all texts and its working fine now. but I want to color mines red. my function just prints the whole game table after getting an input. so I want to colorize the printed table with for example red. but red only affect on the cells which are mines.

Answer (score 2):

There are essentially two ways you can go about it:

- Using the [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles) API (as illustrated in Jerry Coffin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712866/1889329)).
- Taking advantage of the console's ability to process [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)<sup>1</sup>.

The latter is easier to implement and a lot more versatile. For example, it allows you to use the full range of 24-bit colors, something that isn't available through the Console API. The following illustrates how to enable processing of virtual terminal sequences, and how to use them:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>

#include <iostream>


// Define commonly used formatting control sequences
auto const& reset { L"\x1b[0m" };
auto const& red { L"\x1b[31m" };
auto const& bright_red { L"\x1b[91m" };

int wmain()
{
    // Enable processing of virtual terminal sequences
    auto output_handle { ::GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) };
    DWORD mode {};
    auto success { ::GetConsoleMode(output_handle, &mode) };
    mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    success = ::SetConsoleMode(output_handle, mode);

    std::wcout << red << L"Red Text\n"
               << bright_red << L"Bright Red Text\n"
               << reset << L"Normal Text\n";
}
```

This produces the following output:

[image: Colored Console output]

---

<sup>1</sup> *I wasn't able to find information on when virtual terminal sequence processing was introduced into Windows' console.*

Comment: I believe virtual terminal sequence processing is Windows 10 only. It's definitely not in Windows 7, but I don't have a copy of Windows 8 handy to check whether it supports it or not.

Comment: @jer: I seem to recall, that virtual terminal processing was introduced in Windows 10, too. The odd bit is, that the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT` flag is unconditionally available in the Windows SDK. This may mean anything from being a deployment bug in the SDK to keeping the option to backport this feature. Since I don't have Windows 7 (or 8) here, have you tried running the code on Win7? If so, does the call to `SetConsoleMode` succeed on that system?

Comment: On Windows 7, the call to `SetConsoleMode()` fails, and `GetLastError()` returns 87 ("Invalid Parameter").